# How can I check delete permissions on a file before using fs.unlink() in node.js?

Tags: node.js, file-permissions, fs

I want to avoid thrwoing error while deleting a file or directory using **fs.unlink** and want to check permission before unlink. I know I can use [fs.access](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback) to check read, write and execute permissions of a file. But there is no way to check if I can delete a file or not. I am using following code:

```
 fs.unlink(filepath, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
 });
```

Comment: The error itself is probably the most reliable check. Just don't throw it if you don't want to and handle accordingly.

Comment: @laggingreflex that's what I am currently doing, problem is that I am deleting thousands of files and monitoring their progress in a progress bar. Sometime, progress bar is not smooth when there are a lot files which could not be deleted (let say it jumps from 50% to 80% suddenly sometime, which looks not good). I want to remove un-deleteable files from the list even before trying to delete them-.

Comment: One thing you could try is to simply try to move files you want to delete to a temp directory and then after that's successful, delete them there.

If at any point a move fails, you can move everything back.

Answer (score 1):

the delete permission is not depending on the file itself its about its parents.
You need write permission for the direct parent directory and execute permission for all parent directories.